# The requested package league/oauth2-client could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name

Tags: php, composer-php

I copied and pasted what was recommended I use from a thread on so.

Am I using a typo?

```
{
  "require" : {
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*",
    "league/oauth2-client": "1.10"
  }
}
```

Here's the full error message I get from composer:

> /home/wiseman/public_html$ composer update Loading composer
>   repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including
>   require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable
>   set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package league/oauth2-client could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>   https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion
>   for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If Composer states that a package cannot be found, you have to go to [packagist.org](https://packagist.org), type the package name into the big search field and see what you get.

In this particular case, the highest version released is `1.1.0`, so you are missing one dot - or the source you copied it from.